# Asp.net MVC and SQL Server hosting services available

Tags: azure, hosting, web-hosting

I am creating a small website on Asp.net MVC and SQL server. After the development is over Client is now asking help for me to deploy the code. I don’t have any idea how to host this application in Production environment. Can anyone please list all requirements to me like

1. Buy Domain name like www.example.com
2. Do they need to buy SQL Server license as I use basic table and store procedure only
3. Do they have to buy windows OS? As this is very low budget website, could you please suggest the best cost effective option?

I have heard of hosting in Azure and other services are they cheaper? Do I have to buy SQL server license Azure?
The client is a startup company and the also don’t have any idea how to host a website.

Comment: Not a programming question.

Comment: Software engineering is to solve the entire IT related problems. A Programmer is supposed to bring solution for any technical difficulties customer faces. Please don’t underrate this question else I just newly created this account and I won’t be able to post any more questions.
Also please keep in mind that I ask this question because I don’t know how to do it. But what I know is every  software we make has to be deployed in production. So please help if you know the answer.

Comment: But, SO is not about software engineering. There are other websites and forums for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters a shared asp.net web host will do

1.You can purchase shared hosting from many of the available hosting providers you can get a comprehensive list from - http://www.asp.net/hosting/home. Shared hosting is really cheap.You can get it for as low as 50 USD / year and you also get to create a SQL Server(usually providers have the latest version supported) DB for which you do not need a license.You could deploy your stored procedures,tables, views or use Entity framework .

2.Usually when you purchase shared hosting - the provider also takes care of registering a domain for you at a small fee

3.Once you get shared hosting , login with your credentials,you will see options in the Control panel to Deploy your website and you are ready to go.

If you anticipate heavy traffic on your website you could think of using Windows Azure later.

Comment: #muddassir Thanks a lot :) It helped me.